# Sending a cookie as a header from Spring Boot to Vue not being set in browser

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, nginx, cookies, axios

I have a Spring Boot back-end that runs on port 8080, a Vue front-end using Axios that runs on 3400 and an instance of Nginx proxy that allows me to locally access the application from a pre-determined url (`https://app.dev`).

The backend has the following controller (everything irrelevant to the problem removed for brevity's sake) :

```
@CrossOrigin()
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

  @PostMapping("/login")
  public HttpEntity<?> Auth(
    @RequestBody LoginBody session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpsession) throws Exception {

    String sessionCookie = httpsession.getId();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Set-Cookie", "auth=" + sessionCookie + "; HttpOnly");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responsebody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

What I'm essentially trying to do here is that on successful authentication, I send a session ID cookie to front-end for session management as a header. However, browser does not save the cookie upon receiving a response (Application -> Cookies section in Chrome Dev Tools is empty).

If trying to authenticate against the `https://app.dev/api/auth/login` endpoint I get the following header information:

**General**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 21 Jul 2021 14:10:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Set-Cookie: auth=1be8f00a-ccb9-4585-8549-b556046bcc82; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SESSION=MWJlOGYwMGEtY2NiOS00NTg1LTg1NDktYjU1NjA0NmJjYzgy; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 44
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: https://app.dev
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
```

In addition, on the Vue side the request made to back-end looks as follows:

```
  login(session) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'login', {
      session: session
    }, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    })
  }
```

Lastly, the `WebConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addMapping("/api/**").allowedMethods("*")
      .allowedOrigins("https://app.dev")
      .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
      .allowCredentials(true).allowedHeaders("*");
  }

}
```

I am aware that I could technically pass the ID as a part of the response body, but it is an approach that I'm trying to avoid and instead would like to use cookies. Any ideas why the present approach results in browser not saving the received cookies?

### Edit

I tried some information I could find and disabled both CORS and CSRF for the back-end by adding the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

I also edited the Axios request by adding `withCredentials: true` to it:

```
  login(session) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'login', {
      session: session
    }, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    })
  }
```

After doing so, when submitting a request, it still did not set the header, but gave the following notification:

> This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a “SameSite” attribute and was defaulted to “SameSite=Lax” and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage.

After adding the `SameSite=None` attribute, I got a new notification:

> This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because it had the “SameSite=None” attribute but did not have the “Secure” attribute, which is required in order to use the “SameSite=None”.

Similarly, after adding the `Secure` attribute, the notifications disappeared, but Chrome still does not add the cookie. I read some similar questions where the problem was incognito mode blocking the cookies, but it is not working for me using the regular session either.